# Windows 10 Downgrade apps may be removed

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-10, downgrade

I need to downgrade a laptop that upgraded itself from 8.1 to Windows 10 over the weekend. My only issue is that before I do this I need to know what apps I may have to reinstall. I have not installed anything new since the upgrade. Do I have to worry about losing any of my apps that were there before the upgrade?

Comment: Any application you installed since you upgrade to Windows 10 will be removed.  Your system will basically be reversed to the exact state it was before the upgrade.